# php redirect after content insert/execution

Tags: php

i have code like this..

how to redirect after insert data will redirect to domain www.mydomain.com/go/[$no]

sample redirect : www.mydomain.com/go/4656566665

```
if ($this->db->insert('cart_order',$data)){
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            $no = date('His').$id;
            $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('cart_order',array('no'=>$no));
            $items = array();
            foreach ($_POST['items'] as $row){
                $items[] = array('cart_order_id'=>$id,'qty'=>$row['qty'],'price'=>$row['harga_default'],'item_varian_id'=>$row['id'],'item_free'=>$row['item_free'],'catatan'=>$row['catatan']);

            }

            if($this->db->insert_batch('cart_item',$items)){
                echo json_encode(array('success'=>1,'no'=>$no));
            }



        }
```

best regard

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php .. location ..

Comment: Please do some googling before posting these kind of trivial questions. Your question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: This code is not complete. It should be a part of a web service or API. Do you get the response by ajax in front end or in another php function? There are a lot of confusions around your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to redirect the user after logging this page in browser's history , you may use JavaScript

```
die( "<script>location.href='http://example.com/go/".$no."/';");
```

or if you want to redirect your page before reaching to the browser you may use php header

```
header("location:http://example.com/go/".$no);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `header()` function: Like this:
`header("Location:  redirect_web_address");`

If you want to redirect  "www.mydomain.com/go/4656566665" here. You code is:

`header("Location:  www.mydomain.com/go/4656566665");`

So, paste the code in where your data inserted successfully.